# Potential Memory Leak in cv::cvtColor using CV_BGR2HSV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, memory, memory-management

I am seeing radically different memory usage on an iPad3 when calling cv::cvtColor with CV_BGR2GRAY vs CV_BGR2HSV repeatedly in the context of a video processing algorithm and I'd like some insight in to why this is or guidance on how to avoid linear memory growth with each call to cvtColor.

Here's the simplified code I wrote for testing and for context in this question:

```
- (void) processImage:(cv::Mat &)image {
    processor.process(image, output);
    image = output;
}
```

output is defined as part of the class this method is in.  The processor class is defined as:

```
class TestFrameProcessor {
public:
    cv::Mat tmp;
    cv::Scalar green;
    TestFrameProcessor(void):
        green(0,255,0) {
    }

    void process(cv:: Mat &input, cv:: Mat &output) {
        cv::cvtColor(input, tmp, CV_BGR2HSV);
        output = green;
    }
};
```

This code is only meant to be illustrative of the problem I am having not to do anything of value.  When I use CV_BGR2GRAY as the conversion type I get a memory profile like this:

[image: Memory profile when using CV_BGR2GRAY]

With a max value of around 21 MB and an average that is around 10 MB.

When I use CV_BGR2HSV I get a memory profile like this:

[image: Memory profile when using CV_BGR2HSV]

With a peak value of around 225 MB and a min of around 12 MB.  My concern is in this linear growth of memory usage when using the BGR2HSV conversion.  In this particular run there appears to be memory cleanup happening from within OpenCV, however I have had runs (did not get a screen cap of the profile) where the memory grows unbounded until all of the system memory is used up and the application dies an ungraceful death.

Questions are:

- Am I misusing the cv::Mat objects or cvtColor here?  Should I call release?
- Has any one seen this type of memory usage before with cvtColor?
- If so, is there a way to avoid it?
- Are there known memory issues with the OpenCV implementation cvtColor?

(I'm hoping someone else knows the answers or has better GoogleFu skills than I apparently do)

Comment: Such discussions should go straight to [OpenCV Issues](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) where the right people can give you attention.

Comment: Turns out this ended up being a memory issue with the iOS OpenCV camera capture code, not cvtColor.  Once I switched from using the OpenCV version to a native AVCaptureSession and managed the image data manually the memory issue disappeared.